# Utilizar duas classes tipo User no Identity

Tags: autenticação, asp.net-identity

Como usar 2 classes como User no Identity.

Ex. O site terá uma área de administração, e usará a classe padrão "ApplicationUser" que gera uma tabela "AspNetUsers" do Identity para logar.

Nesta área de administração estes usuários, poderão cadastrar clientes que deverão herdar de IdentityUser, os clientes farão login em um ambiente totalmente independente.

Comment: Por que não da permissões por Roles? Role= Admin / Role= Cliente